# I am trying to retrieve data from an API and update my local state. The to convey this updated data to a ContextProvider upon the load of a component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, laravel-8, fetch-api

I find myself navigating through my main page with the following steps:

- Click on the URL leading to '/books'.
- This triggers a request handled by 'react-router-dom,' directing it to the path '/books.'
- The process proceeds to load the parent component, 'BooksController,' which contains child components.
- Specifically, the 'CollectListBooks' component is then rendered.
- On this page, I dispatch a function obtained from the 'useBookControllerContext.'
- This function, in turn, collects data from the Model and returns it to the state for availability to the 'CollectListComponent.'
- Concurrently, when the model is mounted, a 'useEffect' is invoked, making an API request and storing the fetched data in a local state within the model.
- Subsequently, I retrieve the stored data from the local state, which was acquired through the API, and pass it to the 'CollectListBooks' function.
- Upon calling the 'handleRequest' function, it is expected to update the state with the newly fetched books from the API. The updated data should then be visible in the 'CollectListView' component.
- Despite following these steps, the issue arises when attempting to access the state.books, as it appears to be an empty[].
- Folders
- src ->
- -model
- -view
- -controller

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Maincontroller from './controller/Maincontroller';

function App() {
  return (
     <Maincontroller></Maincontroller>
  );
}

export default App;

import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Maincontroller from "./Maincontroller";
import ErrorPage from "../view/errorPage";
import CollectListBooks from "../view/CollectListBooks";
import { BooksLogic } from "../model/BooksLogic";
import BooksController from "./BooksController";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Maincontroller />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/books",
                element: <BooksController/>,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "/books",
                        element: <CollectListBooks/>
                    }
                   
                ]
            }
        ],
        
    },
    {import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useBookControllerContext } from '../controller/BooksController';

export default function CollectListBooks() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useBookControllerContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "LISTBOOKS" });
    //console.log('STATE:: on collectlistbooks', state)
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div> i am on collect list books</div>
    </>

  );
}

        path: "*",
        element: <ErrorPage />
    }
]);
export default router;
import React from 'react'
import DefautLayout from '../view/layouts/DefautLayout'
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Maincontroller() {
    return (
        <>
            <DefautLayout>
                <Outlet></Outlet>
            </DefautLayout>
        </>
    )
}
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useReducer} from 'react'
import { Outlet} from "react-router-dom";
import { BooksLogic } from '../model/BooksLogic';

const initialState = {
    book: null,
    books: [],
};

const BooksControllerState = createContext(initialState);
export default function BooksController() {
    //const navigate = useNavigate();
    const BooksLogicInstance = BooksLogic();

    const collectListBooks = ()  => {
        const books = BooksLogicInstance.getAllBooks();
        console.log(`collectListBooks`, books)
        return books;
    }

    const handleRequest = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "LISTBOOKS":
                const list = collectListBooks();
                return { ...state, books: list }

            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(handleRequest, initialState);

    return (
        <BooksControllerState.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            <Outlet></Outlet>
        </BooksControllerState.Provider>
    )
}
export const useBookControllerContext = () => {
    return useContext(BooksControllerState);
}import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const API = "http://localhost:8000/api/";

export function BooksLogic() {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const url = API + "books";
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);

                if (response.ok) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    setBooks(data); // Set books state with the actual data received from the API
                } else {
                    throw new Error(response.status.toString());
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`Failed fetching books ${error}`);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const getAllBooks = () => {
        return books;
    };

    return {
        getAllBooks,
    };
}
import React from 'react'
import DefautLayout from '../view/layouts/DefautLayout'
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Maincontroller() {
    return (
        <>
            <DefautLayout>
                <Outlet></Outlet>
            </DefautLayout>
        </>
    )
}
```